# c++/cli arraylist ^ (locked the size of string )

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, c++-cli, desktop-application

I'm creating `C++` 'Cli' /`.Net` Desktop application with Visual Studio,
and collecting all my test results into one list as a string:

```
System::Collections::ArrayList^ lineList_type_err1 = gcnew System::Collections::ArrayList;   // list of word  
lineList_type_err1->Add("word list ");
lineList_type_err1->Add("|result  1 |");
lineList_type_err1->Add("|result 2 |");
lineList_type_err1->Add("|result 3 |");
lineList_type_err1->Add(" ");
```

but the problem is that every word has their own size, and my message was too bad. I would like some method to lock the size similar to:

```
 printf("\n| %-25s |","result 1");
 printf("\n| %-25s |","result 2");
```

the size in `printf` is locked to `25`, but I would like to do it with:

```
System::Collections::ArrayList^  ;
```

Comment: Not C++ - retagged and edited title.

Comment: There is no good reason to wrestle printf().  Use Console::Write() and composite formatting.

Comment: I already mention that it's a c++ desktop application, I have textbox to show the result, I m not using the consol also there's many results that's why I m using list

Comment: Not C++ -- changed tag to "c++-cli".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Format` for this;

```
using System::String;
...

lineList_type_err1->Add(String::Format("| {0,-25} |", "result 1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

hy i try your solution with different result , i write this code and  i get this output

```
string liine = std::to_string(linecnt);String^ liine1;
liine1 = gcnew String(liine.c_str());
String ^ mssg = String::Format("|{0,-10}| {0,-10} | {0,-90} |", "ligne", liine1, ": erreur 1. ");
lineList_type_err1->Add(mssg);
```

[com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKZ6S.png)/Lxekl.png

where is the rest of my message i just get
    | ligne |ligne |ligne                         |

Answer (score 0):

this is work thanx to evry one help  ;

```
String^ liine1;
std::string liine;
liine = std::to_string(linecnt);
std::string stdStringVar(liine);
liine1 = gcnew String(liine.c_str());
lineList_type_err1->Add(String::Format("|{0,6}|{1,5}|{2,40}", "line :", liine1, "erreur 1 "));
```